# Subconsulta com MIN E MAX juntos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como consigo trazer uma coluna junto com min() e max()....isso é possível ?

**select Name, Size from Production.Product where Size in (select MIN(Size), MAX(Size) from Production.Product)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão utilizando uma CTE com as funções Min e Max, para utilização posterior em um Join:

```
with CTE_M as
(
  select MIN(Size) as SizeMin, MAX(Size) as SizeMax 
  from Production.Product
)

select p.Name, p.Size 
from Production.Product as p
inner join CTE_M as c
  on
    p.Size = c.SizeMin or
    p.Size = c.SizeMax
```

E uma outra sugestão utilizando uma CTE com a função Row_Number para classificar as linhas e obter o menor e o maior valor:

```
with CTE_RN as
(
  select 
    Name, 
    Size,
    row_number() over(order by Size) as RN_Asc,
    row_number() over(order by Size desc) as RN_Desc
  from Production.Product
)

select Name, Size
from CTE_RN
where RN_Asc = 1 or RN_Desc = 1
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Meia hora de estudo depois , eu mesmo consegui responder..não sei se é possível colocar os dois juntos em uma subquery mas usei essa sintaxe:

select Name, Size from Production.Product where Size in (Select MAX(Size) FROM Production.Product)

union all

select Name, Size from Production.Product where Size in (Select MIN(Size) FROM Production.Product)